# Can you call an apartment a house?

Tags: word-usage

Is it technically correct to call an apartment a house?

The definition on Google:

> house
>   1. a building for human habitation, especially one that consists of a ground floor and one or more upper storeys.

So, an apartment is a building and some of them have more storeys. Still I'm not very sure if this is the correct usage.

Comment: The answer depends on context.

Comment: House is sometimes used as synonymous with home....

Comment: “An apartment is a building” — No it's not. An apartment is a section inside a building, not a building in itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A house is a single unit. A duplex is a house divided into two a units, a triplex is three and so on until you opt to use terms such as apartments and condos to describe the multi-unit structures. Why we call them apartments when they are more together then apart is a mystery to me. A mansion could consist of many units however it is still a house. A hotel consists of many units but it is not and apartment or condo. A house is a home but a home is not always a house.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-family_residential

Answer (score 0):

It is technically incorrect to call it "my house" because doing so implies ownership of the entire building. As stated in your definition, a house is generally an entire building.

Of course, most people would not notice; however, it would be less ambiguous to say "Come over to my place!" or "Come over to my home!" as alternatives to calling it an apartment.